# Recipe database with shopping list generator

Tags: information-management, cooking

A group of friends organizes a yearly meeting for which recipes are collected. Currently they use a wiki. This gives a list of recipes but since there is no sorted list of ingredients needed the shopping trip(s) for these becomes tedious.

Is there an easy to install recipe database with a shopping list generator (web based would be nice, Linux highly preferred) that allows one to easily enter recipes and then to sort the ingredients?

Comment: If Web-based: hosted and/or self-hosted? If a local Linux solution: is multi-user support required (with syncing?)?

Comment: @unor: Nothing is required, although a Windows solution would be very suboptimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [BigOven](https://www.bigoven.com/)?

- It enables you to import from URL/input the recipe.
- It generates your groceries list from the recipe.
- It runs on the web but you can download it as an app on your iPhone/iPad/Android/Kindle Fire/Windows Phone.

Sounds like it could fit.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gourmet Recipe Manager](http://thinkle.github.io/gourmet/)

> *Gourmet Recipe Manager is a recipe-organizer available for Windows, Linux, and other Unix systems that allows you to collect, search, organize, and browse your recipes. Gourmet can also generate shopping lists and calculate nutritional information. It imports Mealmaster, MasterCook and KRecipe files and exports PDFs, webpages and other formats. Gourmet is free software and uses Python, GTK+ and SQLAlchemy.*

### Recipe

- **Create** a Recipe

  - Rating, image, yield, cook time, prep time, . . .
- Enter the **Ingredients**

  - Which can be marked optional, as in the chili example below
- Type out **Instructions**

  - There is also a *Notes* tab
- **Print** recipe cards

### Shopping List

- Select the **Recipes** needed
- Enter the **Yield** for each
- **Add/Remove** items from the shopping list
- **Print** the list

[image: gourmet demo]